# Sentence structure of German

Tags: sentence-structure, passive

I have written as :

Ich habe die Tour des Dresden geplant.

May I write these following to express the meaning as above?

Die Tour des Dresden wird (von mir) geplant.

Die Tour des Dresden wurde (von mir) geplant.

Die Tour des Dresden habt  (von mir) geplant geworden.

Comment: Genitive (»des Dresden«) is wrong. It could be »Tour nach Dresden« (trip to Dresden) or »Tour durch Dresden« (tour through Dresden), maybe also »Tour in Dresden« (tour in Dresden), and, depending on context, even more possibilities. But »Tour des Dresden« is as wrong. Also wrong is »Tour von Dresden«, which someone the suggested in his answer. A »Tour von Müller Reisen« (journey offered by a company named »Müller Reisen«) could be possible, but Dresden is not a traveling agency but a city.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Why do you consider *Tour von Dresden* wrong? I could very well imagine that to be a proper name of a specific tour that is meant to be tightly linked to Dresden, comparable to designations such as *der gute Deutsche von Nanking* or *die Schlacht von Verdun*.

Comment: Mit einer ordentlichen Portion schlechten Geschmacks ausgezeichnet wäre eine *Tour de Dresden* möglich. Es sollte *Ich habe die Dresdentour geplant* heißen und analog die anderen Sätze, bis auf den letzten, der lauten muss *Die Dresdentour ist geplant worden*, nicht *hat*. *Tour von Dresden* würde ich als Tour, die in Dresden startet mit unbekanntem Ziel    verstehen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Der deutsche *von* Nanking (den ich zwar nicht kenne), Hubert *von* Goisern und Rudolf *von* der Habichtsburg (meist verkürzt zu: *von Habsburg*) sind Personen, die von dem genannten Ort abstammen. Sie sind dort geboren oder zumindest dort aufgewachsen. Die Schlachten *von* Hastings, Solferino und Verdun sind einmalige historische Ereignisse, die in der Nähe der genannten Orte stattgefunden haben. Aber eine Tour ist weder eine Person noch ein einmaliges historisches Ereignis (weder einmalig noch historisch), daher passt auch dieses Schema nicht.

Comment: Könnte die von-Diskussion eventuell sogar eine eigene Frage wert sein, ob Zulässigkeit und Stilebene vollständig zu klären?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/32562/1487

Comment: @userunknown: "*Tour von Dresden* würde ich als Tour, die in Dresden startet mit unbekanntem Ziel verstehen." - Diese Argumentation ist äußerst zweifelhaft. Schließlich führt die [Straße von Gibraltar](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stra%C3%9Fe_von_Gibraltar) auch nicht von Gibraltar aus zu einem unbekannten Ziel, sondern quer dazu geradewegs an Gibraltar vorbei.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Der [gute Deutsche von Nanking](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Rabe) hat in der Tat eine historische Verbindung zu Nanking/Nanjing, auch wenn er weder dort geboren wurde noch im engeren Sinn des Worts dort aufgewachsen ist. Ich stimme dir eigentlich in all deinen Ausführung zu, komme aber zum gegenteiligen Ergebnis, wie ich mittlerweile in [meiner Antwort auf die neue Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/32567/5999) dargelegt habe.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: "but Dresden is not a traveling agency but a city" - irrespective of the other points, cities these days do act as tourism companies and offer tours and other products of interest for tourists.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Und die Tour von Dresden führt geradewegs an Dresden vorbei?

Comment: @userunknown: Dazu macht die Frage keine Aussage. Möglich wäre es natürlich, dass die *Tour von Dresden* gar nicht in oder nahe bei Dresden stattfindet, sondern nur einen anderweitigen, indirekten Bezug zu Dresden hat - ähnlich wie die [ungarische Notation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungarische_Notation) gar nicht selber direkt aus Ungarn kommt (lediglich ihr Urheber tut dies) und allenfalls eine oberflächliche und nicht exklusive Ähnlichkeit zu ungarischen Personennamen aufweist oder die Rigaer Straße in Berlin, die nicht nach Riga führt und nicht einmal in die betreffende Richtung zeigt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your examples are all wrong, because you can't literally translate *tour of Dresden* to *Tour des Dresden*. It has to be *Tour **durch** Dresden* or *Tour **in** Dresden*.

> Die Tour **durch** Dresden wird (von mir) geplant.

The tour of Dresden is planned (by myself).

> Die Tour **durch** Dresden wurde (von mir) geplant.

The tour of Dresden has been planned (by myself).

> Die Tour **durch** Dresden **ist** (von mir) geplant **worden**.

The tour of Dresden had been planned (by myself).

Please note there is no direct portability of tenses either, so the second and third example are an approximation. German *Perfekt* isn't a present tense but a past tense.

Comment: Nach Dresden, von Dresden (durchaus) oder besser meist: Dresdentour.