# »Tour von Dresden«: Richtig oder falsch?

Tags: preposition

In einer [Antwort auf eine andere Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/32551/1487) wurde der Ausdruck »Tour von Dresden« verwendet, was einige Kommentatoren (mich eingeschlossen) für eine falsche Formulierung halten, während andere meinen, der Begriff wäre korrekt.

Die Formulierung könnte z.B. in diesen Sätzen verwendet werden:

> Anton und Berta buchten letzen Freitag eine **Tour von Dresden**.
>   Bei der **Tour von Dresden** sah Walter viele Sehenswürdigkeiten.
>   Müller Reisen veranstaltet dreimal täglich eine **Tour von Dresden**.

Zur Klarstellung:

- Mit »Tour« ist eine kommerziell organisierte und durchgeführte kurze Rundreise für Touristen gemeint, die wiederholt (auch mehrmals täglich) stattfindet. Es ist auch erlaubt, unter »Tour« eine individuell geplante und durchgeführte Fahrt (oder auch einen Spaziergang) zu verstehen.
- »Dresden« steht stellvertretend für jede beliebige Ansiedlung, in der solche Rundfahrten durchgeführt werden.

**Meine Frage:**
Ist die Präposition »von« zwischen »Tour« und »Dresden« als korrekt oder als falsch zu bewerten?

Die Frage dreht sich ganz konkret um die Präposition »von«: Ist sie hier richtig eingesetzt? Ist sie hier falsch? Oder ist sie vielleicht zwar eine stilistisch schlechte Wahl, aber dennoch grammatisch korrekt?

Es geht nicht darum eine bessere Formulierung zu finden (wie z.B. »Tour durch Dresden«), sondern ausschließlich darum zu bewerten, ob »von« hier richtig oder falsch ist. Ich bitte auch um eine Begründung der Bewertung.

Comment: *Müller Reisen veranstaltet dreimal täglich eine Tour von Dresden.* Könnte einen Sinn ergeben, wenn diese Tour *irgendwohin* führt. (und keine *Dresden-Rundfahrt* ist). Beim Wort *Tour* erwartet ich eine Routenbeschreibung .. *entlang des Elbtals*, *durch Dresden*, keine Ortszuweisung (Tour von Dresden / Tour Dresdens klingt mehr nach historischem Ereignis). Wobei *Dresden-Tour* auch funktioniert (auch hier ist der Ort nicht so hervorgehoben).

Comment: @Chieron: "Beim Wort *Tour* erwarte ich eine Routenbeschreibung" - Die wäre aber zum Beispiel in "die Tour von Müller-Reisen" auch nicht gegeben.

Comment: Wenn es Leute sagen, ist es richtig, sonst falsch. Ich glaube nicht, dass wir dafür eine befriedigende Begründung finden. Aber schauen wir mal.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper stimmt, und würde *Tour von Müller-Reisen* als Name eines historischen Ereignis taugen, würde ich auch stutzen.

Comment: @CarstenS i.a. stimmt das. Aber hier stutzt man zumindest kurz, was der Sprache nicht zuträglich ist und darauf hindeutet, dass die Anwendung zumindest fragwürdig ist.

Comment: @Chieron, ich finde es auch „falsch“. Richtig wird es imho, wenn man *touren* als transitives Verb benutzt, dann geht sogar der Genitiv. Meiner Meinung nach würde das aber den Sinn verändern.

Answer (score 2):

Tour von Dresden würde nur eingesetzt, wenn die Tour der Stadt Dresden gehören würde. In den letzten Jahrhunderten, hat man sich manchmal so ausgedrückt, aber das neue Wort "Tour" impliziert, dass der OP die Wendung in der heutigen Zeit verwenden möchte. Und das ist falsch.
Korrekt wäre "Tour in Dresden" oder "Tour durch Dresden".

Comment: "dass der OP die Wendung in der heutigen Zeit verwenden möchte. Und das ist falsch." - wieso ist es verboten, heutzutage altertümlich anmutende Formulierungen einzusetzen? (Möglicherweise ist genau der altertümliche Eindruck beabsichtigt?)

Comment: Dann bräuchte er nicht fragen.

Comment: Es ist übrigens nicht verboten. Es ist nur grammatikalisch falsch.

Comment: Und falls der OP es anders gemeint hat, sollte er die Frage vielleicht präziser stellen. Ich kann nur mit dem arbeiten, was ich oben in der Frage lese.

Comment: "Es ist nur grammatikalisch falsch." - insbesondere die [Bedeutungen 5a und 5c](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/von_aus_ab_durch_per_seitens#Bedeutung5a) lassen mich darauf schließen, dass es grammatikalisch wohl doch irgendwie richtig sein dürfte. "Ich kann nur mit dem arbeiten, was ich oben in der Frage lese." - bezogen auf diese Frage könnte deine Antwort aber eher zutreffen; ich hatte (da ich von dort aus hierhernavigiert habe) noch die [ursprüngliche Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32549/sentence-structure-of-german/32551) im Kopf, die weniger Einschränkungen macht.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Dir ist aber klar, dass der Genetiv den Besitzer anzeigt? Wie kann denn eine Stadt ein Besitzer einer Tour sein? Das ist so falsch.

Comment: Wie kann denn ein Land der Besitzer eines Monarchen sein? Ist es nicht, wenn überhaupt, andersherum? Siehe *König von Schweden*. Wenn du die Duden-Beispiele für Bedeutung 5a anschaust, wirst du sogar erkennen, dass *keines* davon im engeren Sinn ein *Besitzverhältnis* ausdrückt, allenfalls eine Urheberschaft oder (noch allgemeiner) Zugehörigkeit.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper "Schwedens König" ist in Ordnung.

Comment: Der König von Schweden ist eine alte Form. Genauso wie alle anderen Beispiele. Und 5c ist umgangssprachlich.

Comment: "Der König von Schweden ist eine alte Form. Genauso wie alle anderen Beispiele." - also auch "gegen den Protest von Tausenden wurde das Kernkraftwerk gebaut". Wenn man deiner Argumentation aus der Antwort folgt, impliziert das neue Wort "Kernkraftwerk" jedoch eine Verwendung in der heutigen Zeit. Wie man in [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Tour%2CKernkraftwerk&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CKernkraftwerk%3B%2Cc0) sieht, ist "Tour" *erheblich* älter als "Kernkraftwerk".

Comment: Was ist an "Gegen den Protest von Tausenden" alt?

Comment: "Was ist an 'Gegen den Protest von Tausenden' alt?" - das musst du schon selber beantworten. Die Behauptung "(...) ist eine alte Form. **Genauso wie alle anderen Beispiele.**" (Hervorherbung von mir) [stammt von dir](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32562/tour-von-dresden-richtig-oder-falsch/32569?noredirect=1#comment80250_32569).

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke, es ist unstrittig, dass der Ausdruck "Tour von A nach B" korrekt ist. In der ursprünglichen Antwort hast du "Tour nach B", wo nur der Zielort genannt ist, als korrekt aufgeführt. Ich kann nicht erkennen, warum dann der Ausdruck "Tour von A", analog nur den Startort nennend, falsch sein sollte, auch wenn man vermutlich ein Formulierung wie "Tour von A aus(gehend)" oder "Tour in A beginnend" den Vorzug geben würde, um klarer abzugrenzen, dass A der Zielort ist und nicht etwa der Erfinder, Reiseanbieter oder ein prominenter Tourengeher.

Answer (score 1):

*Tour von Dresden* klingt für mich nicht korrekt. Hier würde ich entweder ein Ziel erwarten (*Tour von Desden nach ...*) oder ich würde es als stehenden Ausdruck interpretieren (z.B. ein jahrhundertealter Weg, der den Namen *Tour von Dresden* trägt).

Ich würde stattdessen von einer *Tour durch Dresden* sprechen. Dann wäre klar, dass die Tour in Dresden begonnen, in Dresden stattgefunden und auch in Dresden geendet hat.

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe zwar die Frage gestellt, möchte aber meine Bewertung (welche lautet: »von« wird hier falsch verwendet) auch gerne begründen, und dafür ist die Frage der falsche Ort, das gehört in eine Antwort.

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/von) listet für die Präposition »von« nur zwei Bedeutungen auf:

> 1. mit Dativ: Ursprung räumlicher oder zeitlicher Veränderung, Herkunft, Gegenstand der Betrachtung, Ursache, sonstige Verhältnisse
> 2. getrennt stehender Namenszusatz vor Familiennamen (des ehemaligen Adels) und Adelsprädikat (bei Namen adeliger Personen)

Dabei ist die Bedeutung 2 von 1 abgeleitet (der Zusatz nach dem »von« lässt sich immer auf einen Ort zurückführen) und hier ohnehin unerheblich. Die Bedeutung 1 ist hier so schwammig und weit gefasst definiert, das sie bei der konkreten Fragestellung keine große Hilfe ist.

**Vergleich mit »Tour von Müller Reisen«:**
Hier ist »Müller Reisen« der Veranstalter, also der Urheber, und somit kein geografischer Begriff. Diese Formulierung fällt in die selbe Kategorie wie

- Die Räuber **von** Schiller
- Der Kuchen **von** meiner Oma

In der nachgefragten Formulierung wird aber ausdrücklich verlangt, dass hinter dem »von« der Name einer Ansiedelung, also ein geografischer Begriff, genauer: der Name einer Ortschaft, steht. Der Vergleich mit etwas anderem als Ortsnamen ist daher nicht angebracht, weil er mit der Fragestellung nichts zu tun hat.

Der Ausdruck »Tour von Dresden« fällt in dieses semantische Schema:

> <*Ereignis*> **von** <*Name eines geografischen Ortes*>

Beispiele dafür sind:

> Schlacht von Verdun
>   Bombardierung von Dresden
>   Untergang von Troja

aber auch

> Eine Reise von Salzburg nach Wien
>   Die Fahrt von Moskau nach Peking
>   Die Tunnelpassage von Calais nach Folkstone

Nicht in dieses Schema fallen:

> Der schiefe Turm von Pisa
>   Der Dom von Mailand
>   Die Koloss von Rhodos

Ich beginne beim letzen Block und arbeite mich dann zum ersten vor:

Weder ein Turm, noch ein Dom noch eine Statue sind Ereignisse, sondern Bauwerke (im weitesten Sinn) und fallen daher nicht ins beschriebene Schema, das eben ausdrücklich ein Ereignis fordert.

Im Fall der Bewegungen von A nach B kann man die Bewegungen (Reise, Fahrt, Passage usw.) zwar als Ereignisse auffassen, aber das hier verwendete Schema verlangt auch die Angabe eines Ziels. Ohne Angabe des Ziels bleibt sie Aussage unvollständig:

> Mama, Papa, ich verabschiede mich jetzt. Ich mache in drei Stunden einen Flug von Frankfurt.

Der letzte Satz ist frustrierend. Man möchte ihn mit etwas ergänzen, z.B. mit »nach New York« oder wenigstens mit »weg«. Aber so, wie der Satz dasteht, ist er semantisch unvollständig.

Andere Beispiele:

> Ernst plant seine Flucht von Berlin ausgehend.
>   Inge macht eine Schifffahrt von Wien weg.
>   Walter überlegt sich eine Wanderung von der Jodelhütte fort.

Hier muss mit Wörtern wie »weg« und »fort« ein Ersatz zu »nach B« bereitgestellt werden, daher sind diese Beispiele also eigentlich Sonderfälle bzw. Variationen des Schemas »von A nach B« . Viel entscheidender ist aber, dass die Bezeichnungen für die Bewegung (Flucht, Fahrt, Wanderung) allesamt geeignet sind, eine Bewegung zu beschreiben, deren Ziel vom Ausgangspunkt verschieden ist. Anderenfalls wäre es nicht möglich, eine Bewegung zu beschrieben, die vom Startpunkt wegführt.

Eine Tour ist aber ausdrücklich eine Reise, die am Ende zu ihrem Ausgangspunkt zurückführt (andere Bedeutungen des Wortes *Tour* haben damit zu tun, dass sich etwas um sich selbst dreht). Daher kann man keine »Tour von Dresden weg« machen. Eine »Zugfahrt von Dresden weg« oder eine »Autofahrt von Dresden nach Erfurt« wären denkbar, aber gerade bei einer Tour ist das nicht möglich.

Kommen wir zu »Schlacht von Verdun« und ähnlichen Formulierungen: Dabei ist das Ereignis, das vor dem Wort »von« steht, immer ein einmaliges und außergewöhnliches Ereignis, das den Lauf der Geschichte prägt. In diesem Sinne wäre sogar eine »Tour von Dresden« denkbar:

> Fiktiver Zeitungsartikel:
>   *Gestern, am 16. Oktober 2016, versammelten sich Anhänger der Pegida und der AfD in Dresden zu einer gemeinsamen angekündigten Demonstration, die in einem geschlossenen Rundkurs ausgehend vom Zwinger durch die Altstadt und dann wieder zurück zum Zwinger führte. Dabei kam es zu Ausschreitungen derer die eingesetzten Sicherheitskräfte nicht mehr Herr wurden. Bei diesem von Journalisten als »**Tour von Dresden**« bezeichneten Zug rechtsextremer und gewaltbereiter Anhänger der genannten Gruppierungen wurden dutzende Fahrzeuge und Auslagenscheiben beschädigt, ...*

In diesem Beispiel wird die »Tour von Dresden« als Eigenname für ein einmaliges, sich nicht wiederholendes Ereignis verwendet, dass große Aufmerksamkeit im In- und Ausland hervorruft. In genau diesem Sinn ist die Verwendung des Wortes »von« auch legitim. Aber die in der Frage genannten Beispiele legen keineswegs nahe, dass einmalige und beispiellose Ereignisse gemeint sind.

Die Verwendung als Bezeichnung für ein wiederkehrendes Ereignis wie die französische Radrundfahrt (Tour de France) ist zwar denkbar (etwa im Sinn von »Marathon von Graz«), aber dennoch nicht üblich. Wenn jedes Jahr eine Rundwanderung durch Dresden veranstaltet wird, könnte man dieses wiederkehrende Ereignis durchaus die »Tour von Dresden« nennen. Aber auch diese Verwendung lag nicht in der Intention der gestellten Frage, in der aus ausdrücklich um Touristen ging, die sich entweder individuell oder kommerziell gelenkt durch die Stadt bewegen.

### Fazit

In den oben geschilderten Ausnahmefällen ist die Formulierung »Tour von Dresden« bedingt zulässig, nicht jedoch im Sinn der gestellten Frage.

Comment: "Der Ausdruck »Tour von Dresden« fällt in dieses semantische Schema *<Ereignis> von <Name eines geografischen Ortes>*" - wie belegst du die Einschränkung auf Ereignisse? Wieso nicht allgemein *<etwas Materielles oder Immaterielles> von <Name eines geografischen Ortes>*"? Die Einschränkung wirkt momentan willkürlich. Schließlich muss man sich beispielsweise auch ziemlich stark verbiegen, um "Friede" als "Ereignis" zu interpretieren, wie im [Friede von Utrecht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friede_von_Utrecht).

Comment: "Aber auch diese Verwendung lag nicht in der Intention der gestellten Frage, in der aus ausdrücklich um Touristen ging, die sich entweder individuell oder kommerziell gelenkt durch die Stadt bewegen." - wo genau liest du das in der [betreffenden Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32549/sentence-structure-of-german/32551)?

Comment: Ich lese das hier: »*Mit ›Tour‹ ist eine kommerziell organisierte und durchgeführte kurze Rundreise für Touristen gemeint, die wiederholt (auch mehrmals täglich) stattfindet. Es ist auch erlaubt, unter ›Tour‹ eine individuell geplante und durchgeführte Fahrt (oder auch einen Spaziergang) zu verstehen.*« in dieser Frage: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/32562/1487

Comment: "Hier ist »Müller Reisen« der Veranstalter, also der Urheber, und somit kein geografischer Begriff." - das Eine schließt das Andere aber nicht aus. Eine Stadt kann auch Urheber bzw. Veranstalter sein. So findet man beispielsweise ["die Vielfalt und die Angebote von Dresden"](https://www.dresden.de/media/tourismus/pdf/Dresden_Reisen_2016_Web.pdf) in Verwendung (was übrigens, wie oben bemerkt, auch wieder nicht in die angebliche Einschränkung auf *Ereignisse* passt).

Comment: "Ich lese das hier" - ach ja, in Ordnung. Dann ist das bezogen auf *diese* Frage *hier* korrekt. Irgendwie sind wir damit natürlich an der [ursprünglichen Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32549/sentence-structure-of-german/32551) vorbeigerauscht, in der von so einer Einschränkung eigentlich nichts zu lesen ist. Dort spricht offenbar nichts dagegen, dass der OP nicht tatsächlich "ein wiederkehrendes Ereignis wie die französische Radrundfahrt" plant/geplant hat, was *Tour von Dresden* in jener Frage offenbar zu einer unter bestimmten Bedingungen korrekten Lösung machen würde.

Comment: Lies die Bedeutung 2 in https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Frieden dann musst du dich weniger stark verbiegen. Und warum nicht gleich »<*irgend ein Begriff*> <*irgend eine Präposition*> <*irgend ein andere Begriff*>«? Das wäre nicht zielführend. Man muss die Begriffe schon möglichst eng eingrenzen um treffsichere Aussagen machen zu können.

Comment: Es stimmt, dass wenn man "Friede" als Kurzform für "Friedensschluss" verwendet, man näher am "Ereignis" ist. Das erklärt aber nicht andere "nicht-Ereignisse" wie "Angebote von Dresden" oder natürlich auch "Stadtplan von Dresden" (oder ist ein Stadtplan ein Bauwerk?). *<etwas Materielles oder Immaterielles>* schließt freilich aus mehreren Wörtern bestehende Umschreibungen mit ein, sodass eine tiefergehende Aufschlüsselung nicht nötig ist. Ich halte es nur nicht für sinnvoll, eine Eingrenzung als Beleg für etwas anzuführen, wenn man die Eingrenzung zuvor selber willkürlich gewählt hat.

Comment: Eine Tour von Dresden nach Leipzig und wieder zurück hätte ich noch im Angebot, als Rundreise die zum Ausgangspunkt zurückkehrt. :)

Answer (score -3):

Die Präposition "von" ist in "Tour von Dresden" meiner Meinung nach korrekt, wenn es sich bei der genannten "Tour von Dresden" um ein bestimmtes Ereignis/Vorhaben handelt, analog zum [Friedensvertrag von Versailles](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedensvertrag_von_Versailles), dem [Schiefen Turm von Pisa](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schiefer_Turm_von_Pisa) oder die [Schlacht von Sedan](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlacht_von_Sedan).

Der OP [drückte dies andernorts](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32549/sentence-structure-of-german?noredirect=1#comment80199_32549) mit den Attributen "historisch" und "einmalig" aus. Beides scheint aber zu eng gefasst:

- Einerseits ist "historisch" relativ zum Kontext zu sehen. Definiert also das Tourismusdezernat der Stadt Dresden einen Rundgang oder eine sonstige organisierte Bewegung von Touristen (sei es als tatsächlich durchgeführtes Ereignis oder auch nur als Routenvorschlag auf einer Landkarte), und geht es optimistisch davon aus, dass dieses Angebot im Rahmen des Tourismus der Stadt Dresden eine historische Änderung (also eine Änderung, die langfristig Auswirkungen auf den ganzen Themenkomplex "Tourismus in Dresden" hat) herbeiführt, so scheint "die Tour von Dresden" eine legitime Benennungsmöglichkeit (unter vielen) zu sein.
- Andererseits ist "einmalig" im abstrakten Sinn zu sehen, analog zur Verwendung von bestimmten und unbestimmten Artikeln. In der Tat scheint mir die Formulierung "eine Tour von Dresden" fragwürdig bis fehlerhaft, während dasselbe Problem bei "die Tour von Dresden" nicht erkennbar ist. Auch wenn es sich also beispielsweise um eine regelmäßig stattfindende Veranstaltung handelt, bezieht sich "die Tour von Dresden" auf das konzeptuelle Ereignis, nicht auf eine konkrete Iteration - genau, wie "die Olympischen Spiele" nicht notwendigerweise die Spiele eines bestimmten Jahres bezeichnen, sondern auch das Konzept insgesamt.

Comment: »historisch« bedeutet nicht »in der Vergangenheit«. Wenn am 8. November 2016 in den USA ein neuer Präsident oder eine neue Präsidentin gewählt wird, wird das ein historisches Ereignis sein, aber es liegt noch in der Zukunft. »Historisch« bedeutet: Wichtig in dem Sinn, dass es auf nationaler oder globaler Ebene zu einer lang andauernden Veränderung führt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Richtig, aber "wichtig" ist stets im Kontext zu sehen. Eine Neuerung in einem wissenschaftlichen oder technischen Nischenthema ist ebenfalls "historisch", wenn sie "auf nationaler oder globaler Ebene zu einer lang andauernden Veränderung führt", auch wenn diese Veränderung nur eine Handvoll Leute, die sich mit diesem Nischenthema beschäftigen, betrifft. Entsprechend steht es einem Tourismusbüro frei, (potenziell natürlich irrtümlicherweise) optimistisch davon auszugehen, dass ein neues Angebot in diesem Sinn "historisch" für den Tourismus der Stadt Dresden ist.